# How to make rows from two table "Cancel" each other by columns values(SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Say I have A,B two tables, both contains date and time column,
I want A table to look at B table, Table A will DELETE 1 rows from itself for every duplicate found in B table.

| A |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-24 | 9:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 10:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 10:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:30:00 |

| B |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-24 | 9:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:30:00 |

Result should be

| A(Result) |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-24 | 10:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 10:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 11:30:00 |

Following are actual code,
the @tmp_leave is table A,
the @tmp_cancelLeave is table B

I have tried...

- Using DELETE FROM WHERE EXISTS (subquery)
  It removes multiple rows from table A if it find even only 1 duplicate in table B, which I don't want to.

```
DELETE FROM @tmp_leave 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM @tmp_cancelLeave c
        WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 applicant_name FROM @tmp_leave)= c.applicant_name 
    AND (SELECT TOP 1 calender_date FROM @tmp_leave)= c.calender_date
    AND (SELECT TOP 1 timeslot FROM @tmp_leave)= c.timeslot  
)
```

- Using While Loop (It works,but terrible performance and feel stupid ...
  also if the @tmp_cancelLeave have different order then @tmp_leave, it won't work at all.)

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tmp_leave)

WHILE @cnt < @max
BEGIN
DELETE TOP(1) FROM @tmp_leave 
    WHERE applicant_name IN(SELECT applicant_name FROM @tmp_cancelLeave)
    AND calender_date IN(SELECT calender_date FROM @tmp_cancelLeave)
    AND timeslot IN(SELECT timeslot FROM @tmp_cancelLeave)
    
DELETE TOP(1) FROm @tmp_cancelLeave
    
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
```

Please note that it is not the same as simply using DELETE FROM WHERE EXISTS, since EXISTS will remove multiple rows from table A if it find even only one duplicate in table B, which I don't want to. I just want to delete one identical rows from A for every same rows found in B.

I have been trying this for a day or so, any help is very appreciated!

Comment: You want to "remove" the rows, but not `DELETE` them? Seems a `NOT EXISTS` is still what you want, but in a `SELECT` not a `DELETE` statement then.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thank you for replying, I changed my word to DELETE, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: So why is a `DELETE` with an `EXISTS` *not* what you want?

Comment: Because DELETE with EXISTS will delete multiple records, I just want to delete one identical rows from A for every same rows found in B.

Comment: please show us your tried `DELETE FROM WHERE EXISTS` query

Comment: *"Because DELETE with EXISTS will delete multiple records"* Your question clearly shows you *want* to delete multiple **rows** (4 of them). So, again, I don't see why a `DELETE` with an `EXISTS` is not what you want; have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by assigning a row number to each of your two tables, then deleting from the A table where both date, time and row number match.

```
WITH cteA AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date], [time] ORDER BY [time]) AS rn
    FROM A
), cteB AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date], [time] ORDER BY [time]) AS rn
    FROM B
)
DELETE cteA
FROM       cteA
INNER JOIN cteB
        ON cteA.[date] = cteB.[date]
       AND cteA.[time] = cteB.[time]
       AND cteA.rn     = cteB.rn;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a6647c280f649989447f0e0ebfc8841).

Comment: This is what I am looking for! Man you are my messiah!